# How to increase height of Plot to occupy full height space in flexdashboard shiny in r?

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard, facet-wrap

I am using tidytuesday UN votes dataset and trying to adjust a **facet plot** by `nrows` to occupy the **full height** in **flexdashboard** of the plot but it's hardly utilizing half of the space and making the plot less visible.

[image]

**Alternative** is I can make 5 different plots but this will run **code for 5 times** when it can be done in once with `facet`.

I have also tried `facet_grid`, `par(mfrow = c(1,1))` but both didn't help.

### Code:

```
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(glue)
library(countrycode)
library(tidytuesdayR)

remotes::install_github("davidsjoberg/ggstream") # for creating streamgraph
```

#### Data:

```
tt <- tt_load("2021-03-23")
```

```
unvotes <- tt$unvotes

head(unvotes)
```

```
   rcid country       country_code vote  vote_number date       amend
  <dbl> <chr>         <chr>        <chr>       <dbl> <date>     <dbl>
1     3 United States US           yes             1 1946-01-01     1
2     3 Canada        CA           no             -1 1946-01-01     1
3     3 Cuba          CU           yes             1 1946-01-01     1
4     3 Haiti         HT           yes             1 1946-01-01     1
5     3 Dominican Re~ DO           yes             1 1946-01-01     1
6     3 Mexico        MX           yes             1 1946-01-01     1
```

#### flexdashboard

````
    ---
title: "UN Country Votes"
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    theme: space
runtime: shiny
resource_files:
- .RData
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(glue)
library(countrycode)
library(ggstream)    
library(wesanderson)
```   

Trend {data-icon="fa-bar-chart"}
=====================================

Inputs {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------



Column {data-width=550}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### UN Vote Trend over the years

```{r}
# Space for other plot
```


Column {data-width=450}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### UN Vote Trend by Continents

```{r}

# par(mfrow = c(1,1))
 unvotes %>%
  mutate(continent = countrycode(country_code, "iso2c", "continent")) %>%
  # mutate_all(as.factor) %>%
  group_by(continent, years = year(date) , vote) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), .groups = "drop_last") %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  # mutate(pct = count/sum(count)) %>%


  ggplot(aes(x = years, y = count, fill = vote)) +
  ggstream::geom_stream(show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_stream_label(aes(label = vote)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma, breaks = seq(-2000,2000, 500)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = wes_palette("Darjeeling2")) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +
  facet_wrap(~continent, nrow = 5) +

  labs(title = "World UN Voting trend over the years by continent",
       y = "", x = "",
       caption = "created by ViSa")
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `renderPlot` to wrap your plot so it will be responsive:

````r
---
title: "UN Country Votes"
output:
    flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
vertical_layout: fill
theme: space
runtime: shiny
resource_files:
    - .RData
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
```

# Trend {data-icon="fa-bar-chart"}

## Inputs {.sidebar}

## Column {data-width="550"}

### UN Vote Trend over the years

```{r}
# Space for other plot
```

## Column {data-width="450"}

### UN Vote Trend by Continents

```{r}

# par(mfrow = c(1,1))
renderPlot ({
ggplot(iris) +
    geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))
})
```
````

I simplified your code with a minimum example.

Comment: Thanks @Iz100. I didn't know `renderPlot() `could make a difference in that as well. Appreciate your help :)